# How to send a message to an endpoint in Mule 4 to trigger a flow

Tags: mule, mule4, mule-esb

With Mule 3 it was possible to send messages asynchronously to an endpoint using MuleClient:

```
MuleClient client = new MuleClient(muleContext);
client.dispatch("vm://vm.queue", "Message Payload", null);
```

Is there a way to migrate this functionality in Mule 4 since MuleClient has been removed?

I came across a post that suggested getting the flow by name and publishing the message to the flow as follows

```
Flow flow = registry.lookupByName("MyFlow").get();
InputEvent event = new DefaultInputEvent();
event.message(Message.of(payload));
flow.execute(event);
```

but I get a ClassNotFoundException for the class org.mule.runtime.internal.event.DefaultInputEvent

Comment: Do you have to do it through Java only? or will dataweve work?

Comment: Preferably through the Spring or Java module.

Comment: I have not tried it but I found this. Maybe this helps: [Calling Mule4 flows from Java code](https://mulesoft-leoujjawal.blogspot.com/2019/07/calling-mule4-flows-from-java-code.html)

Comment: Why do you need to do this from Java? Understanding the context could help to identify a solution.

Comment: Note that in Mule 4 endpoints don't exist. The method that @HarshankBansal shared is to trigger a flow, not its listener. Also it requires to develop a Mule extension. When using the Java Module it is a bad practice to use Mule APIs or types.

Comment: I have a DeploymentListener that needs to send notifications when the state of running applications change, and I also have spring beans that need to notify clients when certain conditions are met.

Comment: I'm not sure that a deployment listener is supported inside an application. At the very least they are not documented: https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-runtime/4.4/mule-server-notifications

Comment: I tried using notifications, but I couldn't get an instance of notificationDispatcher. The documentation doesn't specify which class this is and how to get it.

Comment: How would I get those notifications to trigger a flow?

Comment: That would be a different question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using Harshank's recommendation I was able to push messages to a flow simply by getting a reference to the flow and triggering the flow by sending messages to the source.

```
Flow flow = registry.lookupByName(flowName).get();
ComponentLocation location = DefaultComponentLocation.from(flowName + "/source");
...
Message message = Message.of(payload);
CoreEvent coreEvent = CoreEvent.builder(EventContextFactory.create(flow, location)).message(message).build();
flow.process(coreEvent);
```

This is a much cleaner solution than what is implemented in the blog and works from beans initialized in the Spring module. As aled mentioned, this is bad practice, but in the interest of time it is a solution.