# Using Mule 4, how can a Custom Notification be used to trigger or send a message to a flow?

Tags: mule, mule4

Using Mule 4, is there an approved way to trigger or send a message to a flow by dispatching a CustomNotification? I have spring beans that need to notify clients when certain conditions are met. I found the solution posted here (https://stackoverflow.com/a/74553142/1932673) that works, but as mentioned by @aled this is bad practice.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve exactly?

Comment: I have spring beans that need to notify clients when certain conditions are met. The bean have to send a message directly to the flow or fire a CustomNotication that can trigger the flow.

Comment: You found a method to trigger flows from Java previously (https://stackoverflow.com/a/74553142/721855). Please clarify what that answer is not useful for this use case.

Comment: That's the answer I posted and works just fine, but in the comments you mentioned mule notifications so I was wondering if there's already a mechanism for a notification to trigger a flow that I'm missing.

Comment: Kindly make that concern more clear in the question. You should also reference the previous answer for reference. Otherwise the question just looks like a duplicate.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps your best bet is to create a custom connector using the [Mule SDK](https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-sdk/1.1/) and provide an [event source](https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-sdk/1.1/sources) that fires whenever your code needs to trigger a flow.